# Search from database using two conditions

Tags: php

I am new to php totally new, please I will appreciate an help on this I will like to echo result stating the price and the route_description and the transport_type. if the user search using from_route and to_route here is my database.

My database:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverlow. You might consider checking out [ask], as this is a question that has been answered hundreds of time, and the question is overall low-quality. You should always include the code you have tried, the output you received, and the output you expected.

Answer (score 0):

you may can run this query

```
SELECT *
FROM {your_table}
WHERE from_route = {from_route_input} and to_route = {to_route_input}
```